# ng-repeat on table within ng-repeat div not working as expected on custom filtered data

Tags: angularjs, couchdb

The following (desired) template does not work as expected (a div for each year, each containing a table for each month - a traditional year planner style calendar):

```
<div ng-repeat="year in calendar | ToCalendar">
  {{year.name}}
  <table ng-repeat="month in year.children">
    <caption>{{month.name}}</caption>
    <tr>
      <th ng-repeat="d in month.children[1].children track by $index">
        {{d}}
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="week in month.children">          
      <td ng-repeat="d in week.children track by $index">
        {{d.day.format('DD')}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

The outer div element closes before the table (in chrome at least) and so the ng-repeat on the table doesn't have the required parent scope. So all that renders is a div for each year.

$scope.calendar is an array of moment.js objects. The custom filter "ToCalendar" uses creates additional properties (year, month, weekday and week) allowing _.nest() to nest these by year, month and week. To give an idea of structure, the following in the template:

```
<pre>{{calendar | ToCalendar | json}}</pre>
```

Results in the following be rendered:

```
[
  {
    "name": "2014",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "September",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "36",
            "children": [
              null,
              {
                "year": 2014,
                "month": "September",
                "week": "36",
                "weekday": "1",
                "day": "2014-08-31T23:00:00.000Z" //Is in fact a moment() object
              }
              ...
```

If I change the desired template so that the table and its child elements are divs  with css "display: table" and so on, it renders as desired. If I change the outer div to a span and with ng-repeat-start (and an empty element with ng-repeat-end after), but keep the table elements as real table elements, it works. This hacky fix presumably works by forcing the table elements to be within the correct parent scope.

It would seem that the filter "ToCalendar" is causing the repeated divs to close early, but why? Why should whether the inner elements are divs or not make any difference?

---

JS Fiddle: [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/george_of_all_trades/fQfU6/) . See comments.

Comment: can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: @DayanMorenoLeon I'll have a go once jsfiddle's up and running again.

Comment: Works on JSFiddle as expected. The version that does not work is being served as a couchapp from couchdb. I'll see if a local version works.

Comment: Works locally as expected. So why should serving it as couchapp make any difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem obviously lay in a different part of the template, as stripping back to just the desired template fixed it.